# How to build a map of the frequency with which characters occur in a file in OCaml?

Tags: dictionary, ocaml

I would like to create a function in OCaml that returns a map of how often each character occurs in a file. For example, consider a file containing this:

```
AAAAA BB C
```

That input would produce this map:

```
{ ' ' -> 2, 'A' -> 5, 'B' -> 2, 'C' -> 1 }
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
let usage = "usage: " ^ Sys.argv.(0) ^ " [OPTION]... [FILE]..."
let file = ref ""
let speclist = [
  ("-z", Arg.String (fun c -> file := c), " compress [FILE]");
  ("-d", Arg.String (fun d -> file := d), " decompress [FILE]");
]

let build_freq_map f =
  let channel = open_in f in
  function x ->
    input_byte channel

let () =
  Arg.parse
    speclist
    (fun x -> raise (Arg.Bad ("Bad argument: " ^ x)))
    usage;

  build_freq_map !file;
```

But this doesn't compile, saying:

```
File "main.ml", line 19, characters 1-22:
Error: This expression has type 'a -> int
       but an expression was expected of type unit
```

How would I modify my code so that build_frequency_map returns a map of a file's characters and frequencies?

Answer (score 3):

Your error is pretty simple and self-explanatory. `build_freq_map !file` has a function type (it returns a function). You are pattern matching that whole thing with `()` i.e. the unit type. So the types don't match.

It looks like your program is kinda incomplete, because it doesn't output anything or do anything with the result it gets from `build_freq_map`. Furthermore, I don't see any logic in `build_freq_map` that actually builds your "map" that you want. So you still have a ways to go.

Comment: Yeah, working on the logic is the next step, once I get it to compile. It's definitely incomplete. How do I modify the code so that I'm not pattern matching against the unit type? (This is my first OCaml program.)

Comment: There is an implicit `let () = ` before the call to `build_freq_map !file`. Since `build_freq_map` returns a function and not unit, that is the compilation error. To solve this, you need to probably handle that return. You can either bind a variable, or use an underscore (`let _ = `) before the function call.